# How to get through error when looping through API

Tags: python, api, github

Very simple question that I have tried multiple ways to fix but I think I am passing over something that is extremely easy to fix.

```
import requests

# Make an API call and store the response.
url = 'https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=language:python&sort=stars'
r = requests.get(url)
print("Status code:", r.status_code)

# Store API response in a variable.
response_dict = r.json()
print("Total respositories:", response_dict['total_count'])

# Explore information about the respositories.
repo_dicts = response_dict['items']
print("Respositories returned:", len(repo_dicts))

print("\nSelected information about each respository:")
for repo_dict in repo_dicts:

    print('\nName:', repo_dict['name'])
    print('Owner:', repo_dict['owner']['login'])
    print('Stars:', repo_dict['stargazers_count'])
    print('Respository:', repo_dict['html_url'])
    print('Description:', repo_dict['description'])
```

Looping through the github api for most starred projects, and printing information about each repository. One of the respositorys' does not have a description so how would I go about skipping over that description or saying 'No description available', while not having my program crash.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you.  Just a simple if statement to check for an empty string.

```
for repo_dict in repo_dicts:
    ...
    if not repo_dict['description']:
        print('No description')
    else:
        print('Description:', repo_dict['description'])
```

Answer (score 1):

this might work for you:

```
for repo_dict in repo_dicts:

    print('\nName:', repo_dict.get('name', None))
    print('Owner:', repo_dict['owner'].get('login', None))
    print('Stars:', repo_dict.get('stargazers_count', None))
    print('Respository:', repo_dict.get('html_url', None))
    print('Description:', repo_dict.get('description', None))
```

it returns `None` if the value of the key is empty.